# Blooming Problems 3

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> *We love springing forward once the time to blossom's right;
>
>   A Brazilian in specific areas may symbolize me right.
>
>   In the Far East I have types as to California trees;
>
>   Sadly a horrible musician has brought my botany to its knees.*

Can you name this flower?

Hint 1

> The "springing" refers to these plants blooming in spring

Hint 2

> The horrible musician line could be subjective, since people seem to like this musician. However, this musician definitely has an ego

Comment: Yay! Another one of these

Comment: I feel the question is a little broad. Because any spring flower you look at, you can find some connection between the flower and each line of the question. I think we need a hint to narrow down the options.

Comment: This hint may sound lazy, but the plant's name begins and ends with an A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the flower

> Azalea?

We love springing forward once the time to blossom's right;

> Azaleas bloom in spring, their flowers often lasting several weeks.

A Brazilian in specific areas may symbolize me right.

> The azalea is one of the symbols of the city of São Paulo, in Brazil.

In the Far East I have types as to California trees;

> 

Sadly a horrible musician has brought my botany to its knees.

> Iggy Azalea. Never heard of her but there is an article about ["How Did Iggy Azalea Become the World's Most Hated Pop Star?"](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/celebs/news/a41270/iggy-azalea-timeline/).

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 1):

Are these

> Cherry Blossoms?

We love springing forward once the time to blossom's right;

> They blossom around February-April, right around when spring forward (Daylight Savings Time) comes into effect.

A Brazilian in specific areas may symbolize me right.

> There is a huge Japanese community in Sao Paulo, Brazil; as well as in Parana state, Brazil; both of these regions feature cherry blossoms brought by Japanese immigrants.

In the Far East I have types as to California trees;

> They're very popular in the Far East, especially Japan - similar to the sequoia tree's popularity in California.

Sadly a horrible musician has brought my botany to its knees.

> There are a couple of songs entitled Cherry Blossoms which have been ...less than well received when I Googled it.

Comment: No, they aren't